# Is it possible to add the same DLL twice into AppDomain or it's better to re-use loaded DLLC?

Tags: c#, .net

My application loads same DLLs multiple times during application execution time.

```
AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(plugin.FullPathToDLLFile);
loadedPlugin.LoadedAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
```

Have I use AppDomain to re-use them or how?

Any clue about how it should be done normally?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assembly in one concrete version is only loaded once regardless of Assembly.Load calls count.

Comment: Also my question is if it will work faster to get assembly from  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() or just to use System.Reflection.Assembly.Load ?

Comment: There will be no difference (except for few redundant lines of code). It will check if it is already loaded and if it is it will return that assembly if not it will load it and return.