# Load DLL from multiple threads in C# application

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll

I am trying to develop an automated stock trading application which will connect to a broker, receive quotes(ticks), process the ticks and execute trades based on an algorithm.
I want to implement this by writing my algorithm in a separate DLL which will have the following method

```
void OnTick(Tick t)
{
  // algorithm here 
}
```

since i want to trade many symbols at the same time, i want to load this DLL for each symbol on its own thread and pass in the correct tick from the stream.
There's a lot of info on this site and others addressing how to load dll from application but i have not found any info on how to load the same dll many times on different threads and pass in parameters to the method.
I want to be able to process many ticks at the same time, and be able to disable trading on individual stocks while others continue to trade.
Is this the best way to go about designing my app ? if so any info that will point me in the right direction or some sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You only load dll's once, you can create many objects from that dll and each object can be worked on in a thread

Comment: Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503890/is-it-possible-to-add-the-same-dll-twice-into-appdomain-or-its-better-to-re-use

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thank you for the info, if i load dll once,  how will i be able to disable trading on individual stock while others are running?

Comment: By using `lock` or `SemaphoreSlim`, the dll's have nothing to do with your problem, this is just normal threading.

Comment: @AlgoAlpha: you don't control code access security by loading and unloading DLLs, that's both heavy-handed and insecure. The .NET framework has built-in features that inherently support what you are looking for... just that you're doing this the wrong way. Look up Code Access Security.

Comment: @code4life I wasnt even thinking about code security, with my minimal c# skills i just thought dll was the best way to go ...very useful info never the less ...thanks.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain so is loading a dll not the best way to go ? do i just implement a strategy class and create instances from threads ?

Comment: @AlgoAlpha: CAS is actually going to be much easier to implement than what you are envisioning...

Comment: @ScottChamberlain can you post your comment as an answer so i can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only load dll's once, you can create many objects from that dll and each object can be worked on in a thread