# GetAssemblies() throws LoaderExceptions after some changes in project

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have a method in a reflection helper class referenced in some points of the app:

```
public static IEnumerable<TypeInfo> GetControllersWeb()
{
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                    .GetAssemblies()
                    .First(x => x.FullName.StartsWith("MyProject.Web,", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    .DefinedTypes
                    .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Somebody made a change(removed some classes) in the project couple days ago and now this methods throws an exception. The exceptions is the following:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

And in the *LoaderExceptions* it describes one of the removed classes.

If I change the linq query to:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain
         .GetAssemblies()
         .First()
         .DefinedTypes;
```

It works fine. I want to know what in that `First()` method could be causing this? Perhaps something that broke the project settings?

**Update:**

Inspecting the result of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` I can find the desired assembly(it is the index 39):

[image]

Comment: A type in the assembly that was picked up by the `First` call probably references a removed class. Is it possible to change the `First` to a `Single` call? That would provide consistent results.

Comment: It is very unlikely that the First metod itself is causing the problems. When you call `First` with a filter predicate you are probably getting a different assembly then for `First` without a predicate. If you call DefinedTypes on the same assembly I expect the error is still there

Comment: Are you sure that any project referencing the assembly from which the types were removed has been rebuilt built ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir all projects works, builds, rebuilds. Everything is fine.

Comment: And the exception is thrown in the `First(x => ..)` method, for sure. It seems that `StartsWith` is causing it, but idk.

Comment: `First` is designed to throw an exception if item is missing. Instead, use `FirstOrDefault`. then check if the return is `null` before next operation. This way, you don't depend on existence of an item. Unless you want to make sure that item exists and don't want to continue if it doesn't. If that is the logic, your code works just fine

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I would check the dates of the assemblies in your output folder to make sure. Is the assembly you are getting the error on the assembly that had classes removed ? Could you post the messages in LoaderExceptions ?

Comment: @T.S. The error he is getting doesn't seem to be related to no matching elements in the exception, those kind of errors should say something about 'no natching elements were found' not thorw type loader exception. Type loader exceptions are usually thrown when a type is not found.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I know. I was just referring to use of `First`. But, yea, the question is misleading as error language doesn't seem to be related to specific code. It seem to happen before this code runs because [I believe] `GetAssemblies` retrieves already loaded assemblies.

Comment: @T.S. My suspicion is that an assembly fails to load properly, but no exception is thrown until you try to interact with the assembly in some way, and this is why the poster gets an error in `First` when they access `FullName`

Comment: Do you have any EmbeddedAssemblies, that may not have been resolved at this point?  This can also be caused by EmbeddedAssemblies, that also have EmbededdedAssemblies themself which are not resolved :D

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir sorry for the delay, i was out for lunch. I have performed a lot of clears and rebuilds in the whole solution, shouldn't this clear the assemblies in the output folder already ?

Comment: @T.S. I got what you say about `First()`. The fact is that **it have to find** one assembly since it is a hard-coded condition. The assembly with the starting name used there do and will ever do exist in the project. I'm afraid it is unrelated to `First` itself.

Comment: @TobiasTheel not sure how to check for EmbeddedAssemblies in the project... looking into it.

Comment: EmbeddedAssemblies are dlls which you pack into your Assembly and set the BuildAction (not sure if it was build action) to EmbeddedAssembly

Comment: @TobiasTheel checked that and it is not the case. We don't work with it in this project.

Comment: Updated the question with more information.

Comment: *"The fact is that it have to find one assembly..."*. That is fine. If you're saying, you want generic error instead of `if (a == null) throw new SpecialException(...);`, and you don't want to handle the condition, it is totally fine. Although, if you're saying you want to find "single" assembly, I don't believe you can load same assembly more then once. So, you would always have either 1 or 0

Comment: @T.S. now this *"I don't believe you can load same assembly more then once"* is new to me..

Comment: "There is an app for that"--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503890/is-it-possible-to-add-the-same-dll-twice-into-appdomain-or-its-better-to-re-use

Comment: Maybe u just have a version missmatch in your assemblies that is causing the problem

Comment: @TobiasTheel strange because we don't change versions, e.g. the version of the problematic assembly is 1.0.0.0 and aways was.. so wierd.